# Why the process is suspended?

Tags: windows, process

I am running an R code (machine learning) using Rstudio on a Data Science Windows Virtual Machine. When I look at my resource monitoring, I see some suspended processes. Is there any reason why?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with your actual workload.

Windows allows processes (which support this, system components of course do) to automatically suspend themselves when no one is actively using them, in order to not waste resources; this happens automatically and has no impact on performance, the suspended processes will be automatically resumed if required.

If you look at your image, you'll see that they are both related to user experience; this will not impact at all your data processing tools.